# Display the drop down values when mouse-over on text instead of textfield

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

please visit [link](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/apple/iphone-4/filter/art_and_graphics.html)

on top left, you can see "**currenc**y" with dropdown box. once you mouse-over on that, you can see as below

[image]

in same link if you scroll down below you can see filters : `Device, Design, Category, Sort by`

once you mouse-over on **Design**, you can see like below image

[image]

I need same kind of functionality for "currency" also.

means, i want to remove the textfield.

once we mouse-over on "currency"  text , it should display drop-down values.

**Script**

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('select#select-language').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('size', jQuery('option').length);
  }, function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('size', 1);
  });
});

</script>
```

**CSS**

```
select#select-language {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: -2em;
    margin-left: 4em;
padding-right: 2em;
}

option:hover {
    color: white;
    background: #0000FF;
}



</style>
```

**phtml**

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Currency:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I dont understand this question,do you mean that you want the scrollbar gone? Cause it is already displaying values when you mouse over currency

Comment: yes, i dont need scroll bar and text field. it should display drop -down values once we mouse-over on text "currency"

Comment: It already is displaying the dropdown values, but to remove the scrollbar you should add overflow:hidden to the dropdown.

Comment: Ooooh, nevermind i get it now.

Comment: if i use : `overflow:hidden` it will remove complete "currency" block. glad that you got now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not tested)I believe this will display the dropdown when you hover over the label with text "Currency".

```
<script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          jQuery('select#select-language').hide();

          jQuery('#yourlabelid').hover(function () {
             jQuery('select#select-language').show();
          });
       });
</script>
```

change

`<label for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Currency:') ?></label>`

to

`<label id="relevantname" for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Currency:') ?></label>`

Comment: sorry for this . how to find out label id ?

Comment: @spylh9999ggr You changed your <select> to <ul>.

Comment: sorry, i reverted back now. please check